PostgreSQL to Azure Database for PostgreSQL Online Migration Wizard
I'm trying to migrate a database that is on a virtual machine to azure database management, when I fill in the information, I get this error. Has anyone had this error?
{ "resourceId":"/subscriptions/{ID}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.DataMigration/services/{dmsname}", "errorType":"Failed to connect, please check error details", "errorDetail":"Connection failed due to a problem with authentication.The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." }



Failed to connect, please check error details", "errorDetail":"Connection failed due to a problem with authentication.The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

The above error indicates a problem with SSL certificate validation during the connection to Azure Database Migration Service (DMS). This usually occurs because the target database is enforcing SSL/TLS for connections. Make sure you have configured the TLS 1.2 version correctly. Ensure your client is connecting from an allowed IP and firewall rules are properly set up. Then you will be validated to the source successfully as shown below:

For more information you can refer to the MS document
